# Matlab ROI Image Processing Approach

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, roi

I currently have images of the following nature:

[image]

The goal is to have the code display the mean value of each of the squares. The position of each square slightly shifts from image to image. The images are stored as 1024 x 1024 matrices (type = double). Any suggestions on what approach to take in this case?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Thresholding + [`regionprops`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) should work.

Comment: Useful post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749443/identify-white-boxes-in-live-video-feed-using-matlab/42752287#42752287

Comment: Any suggestions on how one can go about automating thresholding? Thanks!

Comment: For automatic, try using `histogram`

Comment: Please try to use your favorite search engine first: "_matlab automatic threshold_", first result is [`greythresh`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)